# vertical menu every page & Header menu navigation

Tags: magento

I am trying to customize header menu and **vertical menu** (left menu) in magneto cms  the vertical menu is shown below

[image]

When i click on the category, i will be redirected to next page but the complete list of categories  is no more displayed on that page. I just want the complete list to be displayed on all pages that a user is being navigating through the categories list.

[image]

i am using below code on CMS -> Pages -> Homepage -> design->Layout Update XML

```
<reference name="left">
    <!--<block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/navigation/left.phtml"/>-->
        <block type="catalog/navigation" before="-" name="catalog.vertnav" template="catalog/navigation/vert_nav.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

how to display the left menu in all pages and  how to customize header menu like
 **HOME ABOUT US Blog**

Please suggest me for developing good looking magneto website

Comment: Are you aware of http://magento.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: @hakre: No i never post questions in http://magento.stackexchange.com

Comment: I think your question fits better there than here. I flagged it now for moderator attention to move it over there. You should not need to do anything (then creating yourself an account on magento SO).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For editing HOME ABOUT US Blog you can change header.phtml file. You can also put template path hints on to get all the names of the file used on frontend.

Have you made changes to catalog.xml for displaying category navigation menu. Update also in catalog.xml  file in layout . It will show.

Comment: where should i create template paths and get all names please can u clearly explain.

Comment: template path hints can be made on by going to System->Configuration->Default Store View->Advanced->Developer on magento admin.